# Проблема JavaScript не читается

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть некая проблема, для меня очень весомая. Есть таблица которая обновляется poll-запросом каждые 5 секунд, вcё прекрасно работает. Но в этой таблице также есть кнопка. Если пишу отдельный скрипт-файл, он после первого poll-обновления перестает отвечать, но если в самом HTML писать `<script>`, то он работает. Как это понять?

Comment: наверное, вы не правильно присоединяете обработчик кликов к  динамически создаваемому контенту. Вы же понимаете о чем я говорю, уже гуглили, и пытались решить проблему самостоятельно, да?

Comment: Если честно я не знал с чего начать ,так как я использую Фреймврк Jsf(primefaces)

Comment: teran спасибо нашел одно решение с событием on  место onclick

Comment: попробую с ним )

Comment: но всеже также приму ответ

Comment: я думаю ваш вопрос закроют как дубликат через некоторое время, т.к. тут через день подобные появляются :)

Comment: Нет не думаю так как в стаке ответа я ненашел а нашел на тосоре и еще не факт что тот отв подходит мне

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если отвечать простым языком, то происходит обновления DOM.
Новые данные заменяют старые и соответственно событие тоже исчезает.
3 варианта решения:

1. на кнопку повесить onСlick
2. после обновления DOM заново навешивать событие на кнопку
3. Самый лучший:

> Если у тебя обновляется таблица не целиком, т.е. изменяются только
>   ряды, а таблица остается не тронутой:

```
$('.table').on('click','button',function(){ /* твой код */});
```

> Если заменяется вся таблица целиком, то обвалакиваем таблицу в div

```
$('div').on('click','button',function(){ /* твой код */});
```

Comment: Я сделал это да ю

Answer (score 0):

Если `#content` изминился(добавились в него новые элементы) тогда сделать ...
Проверяет на добавление новых элементов

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#content", function() {
   //Сюда код после измения
 });
```